# Check if current network connection is metered in Windows batch file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I only want to run my [restic](https://restic.readthedocs.io) backups on non-metered networks.

Given this, I want to kill my backup process if I connect to a metered network, and start it (if necessary) on connection to a non-metered network.

Note: I want to allow my backup to resume if possible, so killing it on disconnection is not an option.

I can [run a task on connection to a network](https://superuser.com/questions/262799/how-to-launch-a-command-on-network-connection-disconnection), but I don't know how a task (my batch file) can determine if my network is metered.

How do I find the metered / unmetered status of the current network from the command line?

Comment: [Wireless Settings with PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/more-messing-around-with-wireless-settings-with-powershell/) Maybe this could help. The unmetered/metered status would be the Cost Property in Powershell.

Answer (score 3):

[This snippet](https://gist.github.com/nijave/d657fb4cdb518286942f6c2dd933b472) by nijave does what you want:

```
[void][Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation, Windows, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]
$cost = [Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation]::GetInternetConnectionProfile().GetConnectionCost()
$cost.ApproachingDataLimit -or $cost.OverDataLimit -or $cost.Roaming -or $cost.BackgroundDataUsageRestricted -or ($cost.NetworkCostType -ne "Unrestricted")
```